# Show multiple calendar with fullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

In my project I have users and groups. Every user has his own calendar.
I have a table (events) where every event is listed and a table (user_events) where is written which event goes to which user.

So the group has an admin. And the admin should be able do view all calenders of the group. I know fullCalender has a feauture to show multiple categories. I just want to show multiple calendars with a diferent color.

Does anyone have some experience with this?

Comment: What is your code so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fullcalendar using different [Event Sources](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) for your different calendars. As you can see, you can feed those calendars from json/function/ajax/gcalendar... And then provide an specific color for them. So, with a JSON feeding should result something like:

```
{
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

Comment: How can I load multiple dynamic calendars? 
For example I have a calendar for each doctor in a database, doctors can be many, and for each one many events.